# Уродливое сообщение геолокации при использовании WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, iphone

Я создал приложение для iPhone/IPad, который использует геолокацию с помощью JavaScript/HTML внутри WebView. HTML файлы и скрипты находятся в приложении.

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку определение местоположения, я вижу сообщение, что "**/var/mobile/Application/~~~~/App.app/www**" хочет разрешение на использование геолокации.

Это имеет смысл, потому что iOS, вероятно, хочет, получить разрешение для использование геолокации для приложения и для браузера WebView.

Как я могу предотвратить или изменить это уродливое сообщение?

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полистайте этот вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673579/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-phonegap

Comment: Я натыкался на этот вопрос и они довольно схожи. Но я не использую фреймворк Cordova/PhoneGap. Как это может помочь мне?

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете web view. Попробуйте указать title для данной страницы.

Comment: title в head имеется